# Is there any way to sort the data from database by time, i mean the latest data first?

Tags: reactjs, database, dictionary, mern

I'm currently using the map function which is iterating in the first come basis but i want to show the latest data first. Consider the messages data from the code below. I want to put the latest messages first. Can someone help me with this?
Thanks in advance...

```
<ul>
        {
        messages.reverse().map(message => (
          <section>
          <li key={message._id}>
          <div className='post-container'>
            <div className='user-profile'>
              <div>
                <p className='small'>{message.user.username}</p>
                <span>posted/modified at: {message.createdAt}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <p className='post-text'>{message.text}</p><br />
            <div>
            <div>
            <h5>{message.likes.length} Likes </h5>
            {!message.likes.includes(userdata._id)
            ?
            <button className='likebtn' onClick={()=>{likePost(message._id)}}><FcLikePlaceholder /> Like</button>
            : 
            <button className='likebtn' onClick={()=>{unlikePost(message._id)}}><FcLike /> Unlike</button>
            }
            <h5>Comments:</h5>
            {
              message.comments.map(com=>{
                return (
                  <div className='comments'><p><label>{com.postedBy.username}: </label>{com.comment}</p></div>
                )
              })
            }
            </div>
            <form onSubmit={(e)=>{
              e.preventDefault()
              makeComment(e.target[0].value, message._id)
            }}>
              <input type='text' placeholder='Add a comment...'></input>
            </form>
            </div>
          </div>
          </li><br />
          </section>     
        ))
        }
      </ul>
```

I'm currently using the map function which is iterating in the first come basis but i want to show the latest data first. Can someone help me with this?
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You can use sorting function before mapping like this:

```
messages.sort((a,b) => b.date - a.date).map(message => {});
```

Comment: some context about the arguments a,b please?

Comment: It's like comparing 2 elements with each other, so you want to compare with the date. You can read more here:
https://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/array/sort